# pasar datos en laravel a un componete en vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

tengo problemas de pasa un datos a un componerte de laravel a vue,

aquí esta un resumen,Un cliente puede tener muchos sucursales y quiero pasa ese dato a un componerte en vue

desde e controlador

```
public function index($cliente_id){
    $data=SucursalesModel::where('cliente_id',$cliente_id)->paginate(5);
    return view('Sucursales.index',['cliente_id'=>$cliente_id, 'data' => $data ]);

}
```

desde la vista

```
@extends('layouts.App_admin_ui')
@section('content')
    <div class='container'>
        <input type="text" v-model="cliente_id_html" value="{{$cliente_id}}">
        <vue-sucursales cliente_id="{{$cliente_id}}" data="{{$data}}" ></vue-sucursales>
    </div>
@endsection
```

aquí esta el problema, en la cual no encuentro la forma de guarda los datos

```
<script type="application/javascript">
import Vue from "vue";


export default {
  data() {

    return {
      cliente_id: {}, //aqui se guarde el cliente id
      consulta_datos: [],//aqui se guarde los registro
      editar_dato: false,  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fuera de `data() {}`

El nombre del dato con el tipo de dato
Usa

```
props : {
cliente_id: String
data:Object
}
```

En blade debes enviar los datos con el mismo nombre, si no es `string` debes enviar como

```
:data={!! $data !!}
```